# Very long execution during loop over a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I'm a bit new to Python and Pandas and I'm trying to do a very simple thing, which is looping over a column of a pandas dataframe called df and modify a value, like in the following snippet

```
for i in range(0,len(df.time) - 1):
    if df.time[i] == df.time[i+1]:
       df.at[i,'time'] = df.time[i] - 1
```

df is the dataframe, which has the column "time". I'm looking for repetitive ticks on time, and if two subsequent timesteps have the same value, I decrement the first by 1.

The problem is that it takes too much time! I ran it for over 20 minutes and it didn't end! On Matlab, the same thing runs in seconds. Why is that and how can I fix? I should also say that the size of this dataframe is over 9 million.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some example input/output would be good... what should `[1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3]` produce as output?

Comment: Can you show sample data? Thanks

Comment: For example [1,2,4,4,5,7,7,8] should produce [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]. And it actually does, the problem is that this loop takes too much time (I actually don't know how much) on a 9 million long dataframe.

Comment: @GianMauroMusso so what would `[4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]` be? Trying to work out if it should be 1, 2, 3, 4 or 3, 4, 3, 4... or something else...

Comment: 'cos you might be after: `df.time.sub(df.time.shift(-1) == df.time)`...

Comment: @JonClements it would be [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]. I know it's not useful to the task but it actually never happens that there are more than 2 repetitive timestemps.

Comment: @GianMauroMusso try the above then? Should work for your case.

Comment: @JonClements   Yes it worked! Thank you very much! I still don't understand why my simple loop takes so long in Python and very short on Matlab but it works fine as you wrote me

Comment: When using pandas - you shouldn't be writing Python loops at all - you should look at the builtin numpy/pandas etc... functions so they're vectorised operations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
In [83]: df['new'] = df['time']

In [84]: df.loc[df.time.diff(-1).eq(0), 'new'] = df.loc[df.time.diff(-1).eq(0), 'time'] - 1

In [85]: df
Out[85]:
   time  new
0     1    1
1     2    2
2     4    3
3     4    4
4     5    5
5     7    6
6     7    7
7     8    8
```